# limiting the network bandwidth of a java process

Tags: java, bandwidth-throttling

Is there an efficient way to limit the bandwidth of a certain java process?

I am familiar with solutions like `trickle` to limit bandwidth of a certain process on run time

```
sudo trickle -s -d 1024 /path/to/app.sh
```

But when dealing with java processes it makes it more of a challenge because the application initiates a `JVM` or in some cases a WRAPPER service that initiates a `JVM` - that means that solutions like 'trickle' will not work.

I can try and limit (using `trickle`) the whole java process (by wrapping / messing up with `/usr/bin/java`  s.link) - UGLY.
Does anyone know of a better solution for limiting the bandwidth of a java process (`JVM`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this is of any use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246345/making-a-reliable-web-service-unreliable-but-in-a-controlled-way/3247133#3247133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think trickle can do it. 
I have similar issue and I solved it via throttling bandwidth on a particular port. For example you application opens port 34567 to communicate, then you can apply firewall setting and throttle it down.

On a mac I am using "ipfw", example:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 5KByte/s
sudo ipfw add 2 pipe 1 src-port 6666
```

On linux I am using "tc", examples & source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/

As a final solution, you can create bash script that monitors processes and picks ones you need and throws port throttling on it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. 
Do you have control of the Java code? Otherwise, are you the System Administator?

If you are using a Java code you could use the Socket paradigm and then limit each socket connection by using the following method: *setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth)*.
In the other case, the bandwidth limitation capability depends by the OS and the way the Java applications are executed.